# How to encorporate a loop into my data subsetting

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have a data frame, df:

```
ID <- c('ID1','ID2','ID3','ID4','ID5','ID6','ID7','ID8','ID9','ID10','ID11')
hr <- c(56,32,38,NA,42,23,35,23,25,44,32)
cr <- c(10,20,10,10,10,20,20,30,40,30,40)
desc <- c("yellow","blue","green","yellow","green","green","blue","yellow","blue","green","blue")
df <- data.frame(ID,hr,cr,desc)
```

I want to isolate each unique value of df$cr into a new subset (ie. group all rows where cr=10, or cr=20, etc).  I then want to order each subset, and keep the first unique value of each colour description (ie. if yellow appears four times in the df$desc column, I want to only keep the row with the lowest df$hr value).

I have done this in code:

```
cr10=subset(df,(df$cr==10))
cr10=cr10[order(cr10$hr) , ]
cr10=subset(cr10,!duplicated(desc))

cr20=subset(df,(df$cr==20))
cr20=cr20[order(cr20$hr) , ]
cr20=subset(cr20,!duplicated(desc))

cr30=subset(df,(df$cr==30))
cr30=cr30[order(cr30$hr) , ]
cr30=subset(cr30,!duplicated(desc))

cr40=subset(df,(df$cr==40))
cr40=cr40[order(cr40$hr) , ]
cr40=subset(cr40,!duplicated(desc))

df_new=rbind(cr10,cr20,cr30,cr40)
> df_new
     ID hr cr   desc
3   ID3 38 10  green
1   ID1 56 10 yellow
6   ID6 23 20  green
2   ID2 32 20   blue
8   ID8 23 30 yellow
10 ID10 44 30  green
9   ID9 25 40   blue
```

However this is very lengthy.  Is there a way to shorten the code or encorporate a loop so that if I had a thousand cr values I would not have to type out the above 1000 times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with `dplyr` and:
`df %>% group_by(cr, desc) %>% arrange(hr) %>% slice(1) %>% ungroup()`

```
> df %>% group_by(cr, desc) %>% arrange(hr) %>% slice(1) %>% ungroup()
Source: local data frame [7 x 4]

ID    hr    cr   desc
(fctr) (dbl) (dbl) (fctr)
1    ID3    38    10  green
2    ID1    56    10 yellow
3    ID2    32    20   blue
4    ID6    23    20  green
5   ID10    44    30  green
6    ID8    23    30 yellow
7    ID9    25    40   blue
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `data.table` I would use it's `unique` method after a quickly sorting the data set. This will avoid any by group operations and will use the fully optimized `forder` and `unique.data.table` functions

```
library(data.table)
unique(setDT(df)[order(cr, hr)], by = c("cr", "desc"))
#      ID hr cr   desc
# 1:  ID3 38 10  green
# 2:  ID1 56 10 yellow
# 3:  ID6 23 20  green
# 4:  ID2 32 20   blue
# 5:  ID8 23 30 yellow
# 6: ID10 44 30  green
# 7:  ID9 25 40   blue
```

Or the `data.table` equivalent of the proposed `dplyr` solution could be (as mentioned by @Arun)

```
setDT(df)[order(hr), .SD[1L], keyby = .(cr, desc)]
```

---

Or similarly, using base R, you could do

```
res <- df[with(df, order(cr, hr)), ]
res[!duplicated(res[c("cr", "desc")]), ]
#      ID hr cr   desc
# 3   ID3 38 10  green
# 1   ID1 56 10 yellow
# 6   ID6 23 20  green
# 2   ID2 32 20   blue
# 8   ID8 23 30 yellow
# 10 ID10 44 30  green
# 9   ID9 25 40   blue
```

Comment: I think in this case, `setDT(df)[order(cr, hr), .SD[1L], by=.(cr, desc)]` is better, since `unique()` has to get the entire data (reordered) first... whereas by using `.SD[1L]`, just the indices are computed in `i`.

Comment: @Arun that was my initial thought, but then I assumed `unique` is much more optimized than `.SD[1L]` combined with `by` (at least in the stable version). Maybe I'll add a benchmark when I will have some time.

Comment: Both are equally optimised. But here, it's not the optimisation that's relevant, but the unnecessary copy. Deep (unnecessary) copies can thwart any amount of optimisations we do.. :-P. Also I personally find `.SD[1L]` code easier to read (there I said it :-P). As a general rule of thumb, I defer to DT functions if the op's requirement is the same as the *exact* usage it was developed for... Else, I move to `[.data.table`.

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr` is your friend here

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  group_by(cr, desc) %>% arrange(hr) %>% 
mutate(dup = duplicated(desc, cr)) %>% filter(dup == FALSE) %>% select(-dup)
```

Comment: Oww, didn't now about the slice(1) function, Vincent's answer is clearly better!